# How to inspect the HTTP request headers sent through a HttpsURLConnection?

Tags: java, networking, https, header

The simple Java code below works. Is there an easy way to find out / inspect the HTTP **request** (not the response) headers actually sent?

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.*;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String httpsURL = "https://api.gdax.com/products/BTC-USD/book?level=1";
        URL myurl = new URL(httpsURL);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) myurl.openConnection();
        InputStream ins = con.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(ins);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        }

        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The request headers are the ones you set up, or the defaults. Why would you need to inspect them? Do you mean *response* headers*received from* an HttpsURLConnection?

Comment: I mean the request headers sent, not received. Do you know what are the default ones? It is always best to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can not do it programaticaly, you could use some kind of proxy like TCP/IP monitor in Eclipse. Or enable the debbug option for java adding these options:

```
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties
```

And put in logging.properties (by default in JRE_HOME\lib) the following property

```
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpsURLConnection.level = ALL
```